# Constructing URLs in ASP.NET to avoid dead links

Tags: asp.net, broken-links

I'm working on a moderately-sized ASP.NET webforms site. URLs for internal links etc. are generally set using syntax like this:

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Some/Path/MyPage.aspx" Text="Blah" />
```

This makes me a little nervous since those links are just strings and I'm worried if I rename or move a page that I'll have trouble chasing down all the references.

Is there some ASP.NET-y way to determine the actual path at runtime? I'm envisioning something like this:

```
NavigateUrl="<%= GetUrl(typeof(MyPage)) %>"
```

Comment: If you're working with a moderately size application, it's going to take some time to go through all of the code to change it to look at the db tables.

Comment: I know. I'm not looking for a magic bullet, just a better solution to migrate to.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the method `GetUrl` according to the logic of your folder structure. Assuming that your namespace does correspond to your Folder Structure a basic definition would be as below

```
public string GetUrl(System.Type CurrentType)
    {
      List<string> PathInNamespace = CurrentType.FullName.Split('.').ToList<string>();
      PathInNamespace.RemoveAt(0);
      return "/" + string.Join("/", PathInNamespace.ToArray());      
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you really want is a CMS like Umbraco, Sitecore, OpenText etc.

However, you could knock something up yourself with a database and a table with ID and Url columns. Then you could just do:

```
NavigateUrl="<%= GetUrl("AwesomeLink") %>"
```

It can go off to the database, look up the ID and fill out the link ready for you. It'd also allow you to change links around without recompile.

It's similar to your idea except that you still need to tell it what link you'd like at some point. It can't guess for you.

Comment: One thing to consider with a solution like this, is the ramifications on database utilization.  For every one of these links, for every page call, you'd be performing a database query.  Some mechanism for caching would help alleviate that.

Comment: Yeh I'd knew somebody would come back with that. Naturally I would cache :)

Answer (score 0):

One non code solution is to creat custom error pages to link to other portions of your website or insert a search box in said error pages.   It's quick, simple and also helps with SEO.